# obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I try to dynamically load a jupyter notebook into a module and found a working code example in https://github.com/axil/import-ipynb/blob/master/import_ipynb.py. However, since this implementation uses some deprecated functions and I want to consolidate some common functionality into a single package I want to implement my own version. However, when I try to transform jupyter magic code into python code before execution, I get this strange error.

```
(Pdb) self
<IPython.core.inputsplitter.IPythonInputSplitter object at 0x102198c50>
(Pdb) IPythonInputSplitter
<class 'IPython.core.inputsplitter.IPythonInputSplitter'>
(Pdb) type(self)
<class 'IPython.core.inputsplitter.IPythonInputSplitter'>
(Pdb) IPythonInputSplitter is type(self)
False
(Pdb) super(IPythonInputSplitter, self)
*** TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Here is some context for the offending code:

```
for cell in notebook.cells:
    if cell.cell_type == "code":
        code = self.shell.input_transformer_manager.transform_cell(cell.source)
```

From the error type I don't think this is a problem special to ipython, but I don't quite get it

Comment: can you show your whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This Problem was unrelated to the provided Code**

The Problem occurred because the module that contained `IPython.core.inputsplitter.IPythonInputSplitter` was reloaded using `importlib.reload` between instantiation and the typecheck.